# Android AlertDialog onClick not called

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, onclicklistener

I have a strange problem in my app.

Let me explain...
I have a ListView which displays several items.
When I click on of these items the I display an alertDialog with a yes and no button.
The alert gets displayed fine and when I click on of the buttons, the onclick handler gets called and my code is executed.
So far so good right?

But when I navigate away from this view (back) and start some other activities, then return to this view.
I can select an item in the list, the alertDialog is displayed but when I click a button nothing happens.
It doesn't enter my onClick method.

It is so strange and I tried different techniques to display the alertDialog and catch the events but every time I get the same problem.
I get no dump or logs in logcat...

Below is the code how I call the AlertDialog

```
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {    
    cancelAppointment(position);
}

    public void cancelAppointment(int position){
    selectedPosition = position;
    Util.getInstance().setApptToDelete(appointmentsArray.get(position));
    askConfirmation();
}

    public void askConfirmation(){ 
    String message = "Are you sure you want to cancel this appointment?";
            AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertbox.setMessage(message);
            alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes", this);
            alertbox.setNegativeButton("No", this);

            AlertDialog ald = alertbox.create();
            ald.show();
            //alertbox.show();
}

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    dialog.cancel();
    if(which == -2){
        // no
        dialog.cancel();
    }else{
        // yes
        dialog.cancel();
        if(Util.getInstance().getCreateBookingResult() != 0){
            new CancelAppointment().execute("");
            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody know of this bug? And more importantly, know how to fix it?

Thank you guys,

Any help will be verry much appreciated.

Comment: Your `AlertDialog` and `onClickListener` is correct. It has got something to do with something else in your code. Perhaps post the full class or better yet, zip your project and upload it somewhere where we can download it and try it out. It might have something to do with your `ListView` implementation.